# Angularjs can't edit textarea after ng-model load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

After text area is updated with my text, I can't seem to update the text in textarea.

```
$scope.desc = "";
$scope.d = function () {             
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.stat.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($scope.stat[i].Id == $scope.selectedId && $scope.statDate == $scope.stat[i].StatDate) {
            $scope.desc = $scope.stat[i].D;
            return $scope.stat[i].D;
            }
     }
     return "";
 };
$scope.des = function(){return $scope.d}
```

Please visit this Plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/pVSiNrnAOY0A5v0iTmYQ?p=preview for details.

Comment: @A.B type after text is populated inside textarea... you won't be able to type.

Comment: You are binding to a function that will return the same result regardless of what you're entering in the text area. Angular is overriding your text changes with the result of the function.

Comment: @user1620220 I kinda knew that, what is your solution for this type of situation?

Comment: Add another property to your model, and bind that to the text area. Update the property in the `d()` function.

Comment: @user1620220 and how am I going to get the selected IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You make it too complicated. Not to check or bind data with such a complicated function.

Just check my update in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uX3Zeg1MnDnHorAI1vTm?p=preview). It will work as your requirement.

```
 <select ng-model="selectedId"
   ng-options="ac.Id as ac.Name for ac in a"
   ng-init="selectedId = 1" ng-change="getTextValue()">
 </select>
 N
 <select ng-model="statDate" ng-options="time for time in times" ng-change="getTextValue()">
 </select>

 <textarea>{{textValue}}</textarea>
```

And js code:

```
$scope.textValue;
$scope.getTextValue = function() {
  var selectedId = $scope.selectedId;
  var statDate = $scope.statDate;
  for (var i = 0, len = $scope.stat.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if ($scope.stat[i].Id == selectedId && $scope.stat[i].StatDate == statDate) {
      $scope.textValue = $scope.stat[i].D;
      console.log("get value" + $scope.textValue);
      return;
    }
  }
  $scope.textValue = "";
};
// init text area value
$scope.getTextValue();
```